# Simple use Swagger with Django

Tags: python, django, swagger, openapi

I'm a c# developer who recently switched to python/django (company's choice not mine). I'm trying to use swagger/openAPI to document endpoints but I can't find any way to do so without significant effort. Currently most of the out of the box frameworks I've found require me to use the same object in the request and response or need extensive amount of code to specify the schema. I'm looking for something that will allow me to do something like in c# where at most I just need to add an attribute to specify request/response type. Does python not have this? If it doesn't is there a reason for that? Based on my rudimentary knowledge of python I don't understand why this would be so complicated.

Thanks

Comment: Did you had a look at https://editor.swagger.io/ ? It can generate client code in various languages, including Python, based on the openapi specification

Comment: My issue is the OpenAPI schema generation. It's not straight forward and easy to use out of the box. Setting up the swagger-ui on top of it is not a big deal its the schema generation that is driving me crazy